# Manim animate group and child at the same time

Tags: python, manim

I have two mobjects which are grouped into one `VGroup`.
I want to animate some properties of group and, in the same time, animate children porperties:

```py
from manim import *

class Visualisation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circle1 = Circle(1, RED)
        circle2 = Circle(1, BLUE).shift(RIGHT)
        circles = VGroup(circle1, circle2)

        self.add(circles)

        self.play(circles.animate.scale(.85).shift(LEFT * 2), FadeOut(circle2))
        self.wait(2)
```

The problem is that only child animation is playing for `circle2` (fading out), it is not scaling and moving like `circle1` does! But it should because it is a part of `circles` group.

How to make `circle2` both play his own animation **and** respect parent group transformation? I am using Manim CE.

Comment: see [example for Vgroup](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.types.vectorized_mobject.VGroup.html#addtovgroup) - it creates separated group to move only one element in group. So you may have to every circle animate separatelly.

Comment: The only think which works for me: Every object animate separatelly: `self.play(circles.animate.scale(.85).shift(LEFT * 2), FadeOut(circle2, shift=LEFT*2, scale=.85))`

Comment: or `self.play(circles.animate.scale(.85).shift(LEFT * 2), circle2.animate.scale(.85).shift(LEFT*2).fade(1))`

Comment: @furas I changed my code to workaround this but to be honest this is strange behaviour...

Comment: I think `FadeOut` may create new animation which keeps original values and updates only `fade` value (and recreate other values) - and this can make problem. I tried to use `circle2.add_updater(my_fade)` to add fading - and it almost work but it sends `delta time` to functions and it needs to cumulate value and divide by 3 (because animation takes about 3 second).